# Deep learning: removing batch norm and activation will slow down the training?

Tags: deep-learning

In my project I would like to remove the some batch norm and activation layers. But the training takes longer time than before. The accuracy doesn't drop  too much after training but it takes longer time to converge. Can I know why it happens? Is it reasonable?

Answer (score -1):

These effects are highly dependent on your model topology and the data set.  Batch norm keeps weights from getting out of hand.  Activation layers focus the model's "attention" in various ways.  Removing these makes it harder for your topology to learn from the input.

I suggest that you read a couple of good introductions to network design and those particular details.  I can't help you any further than this, since you've provided no specifics about your application.